# Voltage from IO pin at max current

Tags: current, gpio, attiny

I'm trying to use an ATTiny84 pin to power an LED. I initially thought that I would get around a 3 V output at all voltages, but there is a graph in the datasheet showing that that isn't the case:

[image]

However, the graph stops at 20 mA. I might be using up to the maximum current output allowed from the pin (40 mA). Is there a way to figure out what the voltage would be at this current? Also, why didn't the designers put those values in the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [this datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8006.pdf)

The Absolute Maximum Ratings for DC current per IO pin is indeed 40 mA.

[image]

However, you should not operate a device at its Absolute Maximum Ratings, but at their Recommended Operation conditions.

Although the output current is not explicitly stated, there are tiny notes in the recommended operating conditions:

[image]

[image]

The reliable sink/source current at 3V supply is only 5 mA.
So, I'd suggest using a transistor instead of driving the LED directly by the uP.

> Is there a way to figure out what the voltage would be at this current?

Yes, by testing and measuring it yourself.

> Also, why didn't the designers put those values in the graph?

See, answer above. They still exceeded the 5 mA, but the tiny notes say the data is not guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, you do NOT want to drive the pin at 40mA.  Never operate anywhere near the maximum ratings for any device.  Not if you want a reliable circuit.  Run them below the recommended nominal conditions if you can.  Be nice to your chips, they'll be nice to you   ;)

Anyhow, hypothetically, you *do* have enough information to make an informed guess.

Basically, there's a resistance to the I/O port, right?   (i.e. "Output Impedance")

You have a number of "V" and "I" values, and by using ohms law, you can deduce this resistance.

For the 25-degree line, at 10mA, VOH=2.65V, while at 20mA, VOH=2.35V

Take the difference in voltages, and the difference in the currents...

E/I = R

(2.65V - 2.35V) / (20mA - 10mA) = 0.3V / 10mA = 30 ohms

So if you try to source 40mA, it has to pass through that 30 ohms, and you end up losing (40mA * 30 ohm) = 1.2V

Your output voltage would be VCC - 1.2V

That is, until your chip melts down    ;)

Comment: The curve there is not resistive. While your approximation can be useful, it is important to clarify what it is, i.e. an approximation.

Comment: Assuming that the output characteristic is linear is particularly bad when operating the MOSFETs at large drain-source voltages. They will be in saturation, with the current relatively constant.

Comment: I called it an 'informed guess' which implies 'approximation'.   But yeah, in the future I'll be more explicit.